# Server stops displaying messages, but spams when client is closed

Tags: python, client-server

I've made a simple client-server application in Python, but after 3 messages from the client, the server just stops displaying them. And when the client closes the connections, the server spams empty input. Can anybody tell me why?

Server.py

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 4443

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(10)

print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip, bind_port)

# Ths is our thread for handling clients
def handle_client(client_socket, address):
    running = True
    while running:
        # Print out what the client sends to us.
        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print "[*] Data received from %s: %s " % (address[0], request)

        if request == 'shutdown':
            running = False

    client_socket.send("Closing server. Bye.")
    client_socket.close()
    print 'Server not available for new connections.'

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print '[*] Accepted incoming connection from: %s:%d' %  
    (addr[0],addr[1])
    client.send("You're now connected! Enjoy.")

    # Spin up our client thread to handle incoming data
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client, 
    addr))
client_handler.start()
```

Client.py

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 4443

# Create a socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the client
client.connect((target_host, target_port))

while True:
    # Read some input from the keyboard
    msg = raw_input()

    client.send(msg)

    # Receive some data
    response = client.recv(1024)

    print response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client freezes because the server only responds with data once: `"You're now connected! Enjoy."`. It is blocking on

```
# Receive some data
response = client.recv(1024)
```

You can fix this by printing out server responses in a separate thread:

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 4443

# Create a socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the client
client.connect((target_host, target_port))


def handle_server(client):
    while True:
        print(client.recv(1024))

while True:
    # Read some input from the keyboard
    msg = input('Input:')

    client.send(msg)

    # Receive some data
    import threading
    server_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_server, args=(client,))
    server_handler.start()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me why it blocks? Your solutions works like a charm by the way :o)

Comment: The documentation has the full details - https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html. In short, sockets are created by default in blocking mode: "In blocking mode, operations block until complete or the system returns an error". So when you called client.recv(1024) the  client patiently waits for the next block of data (Which in this setup will never come). The default timeout of sockets is None which means no timeout, so the call would block indefinitely.